# How to remove a div in the parent structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove some elements using a link. The elements that I am trying to remove are in a link's parent div, but i cannot seem to remove them.

Here is the HTML:

```
                  <div class="QR-answer-holder">
                  <label class="QR-answer-label">Enter an answer:</label>
                  <input class="QR-answer-input textbox" type="text" name="answer" />
              </div>
                <a class="new-answer new-qr-answer-space" href="javascript:void(0)">New answer space</a> | 
                <a class="remove-answer remove-qr-answer-space" href="javascript:void(0)">Remove Answer Space</a>
```

Here is the JQuery:

```
      $remove_qr_answer = $(".remove-qr-answer-space");
  $remove_qr_answer.live("click", function() {
      $(this).parent.$(".QR-answer-holder").$(".QR-answer-label").remove();
      $(this).parent.$(".QR-answer-holder").$(".QR-answer-input").remove();

  });
```

Is there anyway to make it so the remove button removes the label and input closest to the end of the div? (or does it do that automatically)?

Comment: Apart from possible structural errors, it should be `.parent(".QR-answer-holder")`, whiteout the `.$`. `parent` is a function. Your code tries to execute the function hold by property `$` of object `parent` and I don't think that one exists.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the `.parent()` node from that `anchor` *.new-qr-answer-space*.

Infact, you need to get the `.sibling()`, since the `div.QR-answer-holder` is **not** the parent node:

```
$remove_qr_answer = $(".remove-qr-answer-space");
$remove_qr_answer.live("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".QR-answer-holder").find(".QR-answer-label:last, .QR-answer-input:last").remove();
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to only get it to remove the last instance of the label and input found in the div? Right now, I have a method that creates multiple labels and inputs in the div. This method will remove all of them.

Answer (score 0):

`parent` is a method, not a property. There is no `$` method in the jQuery object, you use the `find` method to locate children:

```
$(this).parent().find(".QR-answer-holder .QR-answer-label").remove();
$(this).parent().find(".QR-answer-holder .QR-answer-input").remove();
```

#### Edit:

As you actually want to get the closest sibling before the link, you should use the `prev` method instead:

```
$(this).prev().find(".QR-answer-holder .QR-answer-label").remove();
$(this).prev().find(".QR-answer-holder .QR-answer-input").remove();
```

Or if you want to remove all elements in the div, simply:

```
$(this).prev().empty();
```

Comment: it's not the parent node, but a sibling.

Comment: @jAndy: I see. I was looking more at correcting the code than it's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/AvQy5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="QR-answer-holder">
    <label class="QR-answer-label">Enter an answer:</label>
    <input class="QR-answer-input textbox" type="text" name="answer" />
</div>
<a class="new-answer new-qr-answer-space" href="#">New answer space</a> | 
<a class="remove-answer remove-qr-answer-space" href="#">Remove Answer Space</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$remove_qr_answer = $(".remove-qr-answer-space");
$remove_qr_answer.live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings(".QR-answer-holder").find(".QR-answer-label,.QR-answer-input").remove();
});
```

Comment: same here, `div.QR-answer-holder` is not the parent node at all.

Comment: Hello, I have another Jquery function which adds a label and input element. When I use Jquery to add a label and input, then click on the link to remove the newly added elements, your function does not work (i thought the live and click fixed that).

Comment: @jAndy It's not the parent and I'm not using `.parent('.QR-answer-holder')` to get it, sibling is the better option though I wasn't aware of it so will update my answer to use it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$remove_qr_answer = $(".remove-qr-answer-space");   
$remove_qr_answer.live("click", function() {
       $(this).parent().find($(".QR-answer-holder").remove();        
});
```

and it should remove the lable and input as those are inside the placeholder

Answer (score 0):

see [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(this).siblings('.QR-answer-holder .QR-answer-label').remove();
```

this would remove the elements '.QR-answer-holder .QR-answer-label' from the same dom node as this.